# Pandas: drop row if more than one of multiple columns is zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

```
     col0   col1  col2  col3
ID1    0      2     0     2
ID2    1      1     2     10
ID3    0      1     3     4
```

I want to remove rows that contain zeros more than once.

I've tried to do:

```
cols = ['col1', etc]
df.loc[:, cols].value_counts()
```

But this only works for series and not dataframes.

```
df.loc[:, cols].count(0) <= 1
```

Only returns bools.

I feel like I'm close with the 2nd attempt here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply the condition and count the `True` values.

```
(df == 0).sum(1)

ID1    2
ID2    0
ID3    1
dtype: int64

df[(df == 0).sum(1) < 2]

     col0  col1  col2  col3
ID2     1     1     2    10
ID3     0     1     3     4
```

Alternatively, convert the integers to bool and sum that. A little more direct.

```
# df[(~df.astype(bool)).sum(1) < 2]
df[df.astype(bool).sum(1) > len(df.columns)-2]  # no inversion needed

     col0  col1  col2  col3
ID2     1     1     2    10
ID3     0     1     3     4
```

---

For performance, you can use `np.count_nonzero`:

```
# df[np.count_nonzero(df, axis=1) > len(df.columns)-2]
df[np.count_nonzero(df.values, axis=1) > len(df.columns)-2]

     col0  col1  col2  col3
ID2     1     1     2    10
ID3     0     1     3     4
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df[(df == 0).sum(1) < 2]
%timeit df[df.astype(bool).sum(1) > len(df.columns)-2]
%timeit df[np.count_nonzero(df.values, axis=1) > len(df.columns)-2]

7.13 ms ± 161 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.28 ms ± 120 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
997 µs ± 38.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice one. And if I want to further restrict the column checking, I can do `df[(df[my_cols] == 0).sum(1) < 2]`, right? Assuming that I have a much larger dataset to begin with

Comment: @PeptideWitch Yes, that should suffice.

Comment: Interesting #3method there - I quite like that one. Works well for my dataset too

Comment: what means len(df.columns) - 2)..?? @cs95

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
df.loc[df.eq(0).sum(1).le(1),]
     col0  col1  col2  col3
ID2     1     1     2    10
ID3     0     1     3     4
```

A fun way

```
df.mask(df.eq(0)).dropna(0, thresh=df.shape[1] - 1).fillna(0)
     col0  col1  col2  col3
ID2   1.0     1   2.0    10
ID3   0.0     1   3.0     4
```

Comment: Are you using `loc` to [avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/53954986#53954986)?

Comment: Method #1 works but only returns the IDs of the dataset, so you'd have to wrap this inside a condition to filter out the dataframe to begin with. Still, neat answer. Ty :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(subset=df.columns, thresh=2, inplace=True)
df.fillna(0., inplace=True)
```